# Getting errors from crtdefs.h

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, compilation

After a battle trying to include ncurses in my project with makefile, when i try to make .o files it gaves me this errors:

```
In file included from C:/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stddef.h:7,
                 from C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/stddef.h:1,
                 from C:/MinGW/include/stdint.h:54,
                 from C:/MinGW/include/ncursesw/curses.h:63,
                 from src/main.c:1:
C:/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/crtdefs.h:35:18: error: expected ';' before 'typedef'
 __MINGW_EXTENSION typedef unsigned __int64 size_t;
                  ^~~~~~~~
                  ;
C:/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/crtdefs.h:45:18: error: expected ';' before 'typedef'
 __MINGW_EXTENSION typedef __int64 ssize_t;
                  ^~~~~~~~
                  ;
C:/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/crtdefs.h:62:18: error: expected ';' before 'typedef'
 __MINGW_EXTENSION typedef __int64 intptr_t;
                  ^~~~~~~~
                  ;
C:/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/crtdefs.h:75:18: error: expected ';' before 'typedef'
 __MINGW_EXTENSION typedef unsigned __int64 uintptr_t;
                  ^~~~~~~~
                  ;
C:/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/crtdefs.h:88:18: error: expected ';' before 'typedef'
 __MINGW_EXTENSION typedef __int64 ptrdiff_t;
                  ^~~~~~~~
                  ;
C:/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/crtdefs.h:123:18: error: expected ';' before 'typedef'
 __MINGW_EXTENSION typedef __int64 __time64_t;
                  ^~~~~~~~
                  ;
In file included from C:/MinGW/include/stdio.h:94,
                 from C:/MinGW/include/ncursesw/curses.h:164,
                 from src/main.c:1:
C:/MinGW/include/sys/types.h:123:21: error: conflicting types for 'ssize_t'
   typedef _ssize_t  ssize_t;
                     ^~~~~~~
In file included from C:/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stddef.h:7,
                 from C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/stddef.h:1,
                 from C:/MinGW/include/stdint.h:54,
                 from C:/MinGW/include/ncursesw/curses.h:63,
                 from src/main.c:1:
C:/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/crtdefs.h:45:35: note: previous declaration of 'ssize_t' was here
 __MINGW_EXTENSION typedef __int64 ssize_t;
```

This is my makefile:

```
PROJECT=ProjectName

CC=gcc

CFLAGS=-Wall -std=c11
CPPFLAGS = -MMD -MP
CFLAGS   = -Wall $(INC) -g3
LIBS     = -L"C:/MinGW/lib" -L"C:/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib" -g3
INC      = -I"C:/MinGW/include" -I"C:/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include"

SRC_DIR:=src
OBJ_DIR:=obj
BIN_DIR:=bin
EXE:=$(BIN_DIR)/$(PROJECT)

SRC:=$(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)
OBJ:=$(SRC:$(SRC_DIR)/%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)

-include $(OBJ:.o=.d)

all: $(EXE)

.PHONY: all clean

$(EXE): $(OBJ) | $(BIN_DIR)
    @echo ---------------------------Linking
    $(CC) $(OBJ) -o $@ $(LIBS)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC) | $(OBJ_DIR)
    @echo ---------------------------Creating .o files
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(CFLAGS)

$(OBJ_DIR) $(BIN_DIR):
    @echo ---------------------------Creating Directory
    mkdir $@
    @echo ---------------------------Directory Created

clean:
    @echo ---------------------------Clean started
    rmdir /Q /S $(OBJ_DIR)
    rmdir /Q /S $(BIN_DIR)
    @echo ---------------------------Clean finished
```

I am learning to programming in C and i couldn't found nothing related with this and others errors with ncurses saying that curses.h didn't exist(i tried this both directives ncursesw/curses.h and curses.h). I dont know if OS matter but I'm running in windows. The main code is just a test code for this compilation:

```
#include <ncursesw/curses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int x=10;
    initscr();
    raw();
    printw("%d",x);
    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add the source code for main.c up to where it includes curses.h.

Comment: Did you perhaps copy your source file from Linux without converting line endings?  Or paste it from a non-ASCII source?

Comment: Yeah must be that, because i downloaded the x86_64-posix-seh, i will try to change to win version

Answer (score 0):

I just reinstalled MinGw Posix and didn't merge the opt folder with include folder, probably I accidentally rewrited crtdefs.h the first time i installed MinGW.